# Python: "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" for function including qcut within groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, data-binding, group-by, typeerror

I am trying to use my function that extracts bin by qcut, which  is based on a subset of grouped dataframe, and apply cut using that bin to get deciles. These operations are all iterating over groups (year and month).

Here is function:

```
def func(group):
    q, bins = pd.qcut(group.apply(lambda x: x[x['exchcd'] == 1]), 10, retbins=True)
    group =  pd.cut(group, bins, labels=np.arange(10, 0, -1))
    return group
```

- it is intentional that bin extractiion is based on qcut, and applying it by cut.
- `apply(lambda x: x[x['exchcd'] == 1]`) does subsetting.

This is groupby operation in which I am using function:

```
df_master_return['ME_decile']=df_master_return.groupby(
    ['year', 'month'])['ME'].transform(func)
```

However, within function that I wrote, an error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" appears.

searched here, but cannot find similar issues. 
I will appreciate if anyone could tel me what direction solution should be.